# Transferring games from my friends PS4 to mine

Tags: ps4, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

My friend downloaded a game and the game is about 200 GB so I don’t have that much internet capacity so I want to transfer the game to a external hard drive and again I want to transfer the game from the external hard drive to my PS4. The game Is free. I use different PS accounts in his and my PS4; can I still transfer the downloaded free game ? 
Thank you

Comment: Is that game you refer to indeed Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3 (and Multiplayer, I presume, since the base game is certainly not free)?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it as described. Save/backup data is stored on the removable device bound to the user ID. If you logged into your profile on his PSN and redownloaded the game from his system then backed up the game to a removable drive, you might be able to copy the backup to your system while logged into the same user ID you used for the download.

Also, once you've copied the data you may still need an Internet connection to activate your license even though it is a free game.